# HTML5 Placeholder cut off in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, placeholder

In Internet Explorer 9-11 my html5 placeholders are falling below the input containers. I have read through a number of posts on here about html5 placeholder problems in IE, but the only solution I've seen is the to use a jquery plugin. I added this plugin, but it unfortunately had no effect: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder.

I've tried more CSS solutions than I can count like adding padding, removing padding, setting a minimum height, removing the minimum height, increasing the line height, etc. Here is what is looks like now with increased padding: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH5KB.png. There's plenty of space for it, but it still cuts off.

In Chrome and FF, it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGn2C.png (which is how it's supposed to look).

You can view a sandbox of the site here and get a good look at my CSS. The form is in the sidebar (although all the forms on the site are suffering from the same problem. http://hracuity.staging.wpengine.com/blog/

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was a line-height problem. I had the line-height set to 1.75 which caused a portion of the placeholders text to be cut off. Setting the line-height to 1 fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue with line-height causing placeholder cut of at bottom.

Solution that worked for me was to reset `line-height` back to normal (to avoid cutting of text) and to set `display` to `inline-block` (to position placeholder in reference to input `line-height`)

```
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  line-height: normal;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help:

```
// FUNCTION TO SET PLACEHOLDER IN I.E.

(function($) {
    function toggleLabel() {
        var input = $(this);

        if (!input.parent().hasClass('placeholder')) {
            var label = $('<label>').addClass('placeholder');
            input.wrap(label);

            var span = $('<span>');
            span.text(input.attr('placeholder'))
            input.removeAttr('placeholder');
            span.insertBefore(input);
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            var def = input.attr('title');
            if (!input.val() || (input.val() == def)) {
                input.prev('span').css('visibility', '');
                if (def) {
                    var dummy = $('<label></label>').text(def).css('visibility','hidden').appendTo('body');
                    input.prev('span').css('margin-left', dummy.width() + 3 + 'px');
                    dummy.remove();
                }
            } else {
                input.prev('span').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            }
        }, 0);
    };

    function resetField() {
        var def = $(this).attr('title');
        if (!$(this).val() || ($(this).val() == def)) {
            $(this).val(def);
            $(this).prev('span').css('visibility', '');
        }
    };

    var fields = $('input, textarea');

    fields.live('keydown', toggleLabel);
    fields.live('paste', toggleLabel);
    fields.live('focusin', function() {
        $(this).prev('span').css('color', '#000000');
    });
    fields.live('focusout', function() {
        $(this).prev('span').css('color', '#000000');
    });

    $(function() {
       $('input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]').each(
           function() { toggleLabel.call(this); }
       );
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. Unfortunately, that didn't do it. I added the script and it caused some odd behavior. In Chrome, it moved my placeholders outside of the their inputs entirely: http://i.imgur.com/54GpNCQ.png and in IE, it put them next to the inputs and changed the layout: http://i.imgur.com/G7KcUh4.png

Comment: Yes, I had quit the same problem when displaying them.
You need to adjust the position of them. Maybe `display:inline-block` or `position: relative;` should display it well?

Answer (score 0):

This will fix it:

```
input.mycustomclass:-ms-input-placeholder {
    line-height: 1;
}
```